# Angular Posting Form Data (Text Input) To Rest API

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, typescript, express

I'm trying to post data (text input) from a reactive form to the REST API on my local express.js server. Name, surname, email... just basic text input fields.

here I send the value from Form to a service (Form.Component.ts)

```
  onSubmit(formDirective) 
 {
  this.personservice.senddata(this.personForm.value).subscribe(data=>{
  console.log(data);
  })
 }
```

And in the service I post the data to the REST API

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
  {
    console.log('init PS')
  }

  getPeople(): Observable<People[]> 
  {
    return this.http
      .get<People[]>(this._peopleURL)
      .map( (data: any) => data.people);
  }

  private _peopleURL = "http://localhost:8080/api/people";

  senddata(data : any) 
  {
  var body = JSON.stringify(data);
         var headers = new Headers();
         headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         return this.http.post(this._peopleURL, data);
  }
```

The console log displays the correct data but it doesn't post the data to the REST API.
[image]

Which steps have I missed?

EDIT:

```
Here is the code for my express.js server

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const cors = require('cors')

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
  }

  app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server gestartet');
});


app.route('/api/people').get((req, res) => {
    res.send({
      people: [
      { vorname: 'max', nachname: 'müller', email: 'testmail@gmail.com', status: 'true', activity: 'Office' }, 
      { vorname: 'jeremy', nachname: 'püringer', email: 'jp@gmail.com', status: 'true', activity: 'Office' },
      { vorname: 'peter', nachname: 'schmidt', email: 'ps@bluwin.ch', status: 'false', activity: 'service' }
    ]
    });
  });

app.route('/api/people/:vorname').get((req, res) => {
    const requestedPersonSurname = req.params['vorname'];
    res.send({ vorname: requestedPersonSurname });
  });

app.route('/api/save').get()


  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.route('/api/people').post((req, res) => {
    res.send(201, req.body);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 senddata(data: any) {
    var body = JSON.stringify(data);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');;
    return this.http.post(this._peopleURL, data);
  }
```

> Notice that we are building the HTTPHeaders object by chaining successive set() methods. This is because HTTPHeaders is immutable, and its API methods do not cause object mutation. Instead, a call to set will return a new HTTPHeaders object containing the new value properties.

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbfy1a?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you :)
But it tells me that the type "void" can't be assigned to type "Headers" in this line:
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');;

Comment: @JeremyPüringer:  on which line?

Comment: headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');;

Comment: make sure you are creating instance of  `HttpHeaders` not `Headers`

Comment: Thanks :) Again, the values are being sent but not appearing in my REST api :/

Comment: try this `return this.http.post(this._peopleURL, body);` without JSON.stringify

Comment: Trying the postman request right now but I added my server code in the post for you to look at

Comment: So, I'm guessing I'm missing code to be able to Post data, right?

Comment: @JeremyPüringer : Yes

Comment: Alright, sorry for the mistake. I didn't get an error in my console unforunately.

Comment: So, I should be able to Post Data with my server side code as it is right now? Or what should I be looking into?

Comment: I tested your server side code with postman it was giving me the correct result . just put some console.log statement in your server side code and check the result

Comment: try this `app.route('/api/people').post((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(201, req.body);
  });`

Comment: now it shows this:
undefined
express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead index.js:43:76
undefined

Comment: It seems like it's because I didn't have an app route for posting data

Comment: try this `app.post('/api/people',(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(201, req.body);
  });`

Comment: Alright, now it's displaying all the values in the console :)

Comment: It really did, thank you so much!
One more questions, how can I get the form values in my index.js and pass them to the API?

Comment: All the form data is available in req.body

Comment: app.post('/api/people', function(req, res){
    res.send({
      people: [
      { vorname: req.body.vorname, nachname: req.body.nachname, email: req.body.email, status: req.body.status, activity: req.body.activity }
    ]
    });
    
});

Trying to post it like this but it doesn't work :/

Comment: No error message, I just get the form values in my console log and in my browser I can also see that all the data is being sent to the server but for some reason it doesn't post

Comment: where you want to post the value

Comment: I want to post in /api/people

Comment: just add this `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` above body parser